# Can I compile the code on the fly in Delphi and execute it?

Tags: delphi, winapi, assembly, compilation, interpreter

Is it possible to generate an array of bytes and then have Windows execute it like a normal code?
Say we have some assembly code:

```
inc  ecx
```

which is part of a program. After we compile with Nasm we get an EXE in which the above line is converted into something like this:

```
00000035 41
```

Would it be possible to create an array of bytes, fill it with the above bytes and execute- so the incrementation actually takes place?

I have made my super-simple interpreted language but since it is interpreted it's pretty slow. I don't want to write a real compiler for it but I would like to make it faster- compile and run on the fly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely. Processors and operating systems that support data-execution prevention may balk, but that's easy to circumvent. Simply call [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898.aspx) to mark the block of memory as executable. It might be best to use `VirtualAlloc` to allocate the memory you plan on executing. That way, you have an entire page of memory dedicated exclusively to executable code. If you call `VirtualProtect` to make some arbitrary memory you allocated with `GetMem` executable, it will actually mark the entire page that way, so you might accidentally mark some *data* as executable. If that data gets compromised, it might get executed. That's exactly what DEP is meant to protect against, so it's better to keep data and executable code in separately protected regions.

Keep in mind that the task of converting textual code into machine code *is* compiling, so if you don't want to write a real compiler, you might not want to generate machine code after all.

Comment: Thank you. It is "compilation" but without all the EXE headers, linking of external libraries and such. So it should be easier.

Comment: You still need to relocate (fixup) it. Unless you don't use any data (or address it indirectly via a pointer that is passed in registers on startup) and only near branching or PIC.

Answer (score 7):

```
const
   size = 32768;
type
   TFuncInt = function(param: Integer): Integer; // EAX -> EAX
   TByteArray = array[0..size-1] of Byte;
   PByteArray = ^TByteArray;
var
   arr: PByteArray;
   func_param: Integer;
   func_result: Integer;
begin
   arr := VirtualAlloc(nil, size, $3000, $40);
   if arr <> nil then begin
     arr[0] := $40;  // inc EAX
     arr[1] := $C3;  // ret
     func_param := 77;
     func_result := TFuncInt(arr)(func_param);  // 78
     VirtualFree(arr, 0, $8000);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @RobKennedy - Your version of code would not compile.  `Page_Execute_ReadWrite` is not defined in Delphi7.  You should define it manually.  Or use numeric value instead.

Comment: So define it, then. I don't care how outdated your development environment is; don't use bare numbers. They mean nothing to anyone reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think modern processors with Data Execution Prevention (DEP) will disallow this.
Note that there are several pascal scripting libraries available, for such purposes.

Comment: I know they are, like RemObjects Pascal Script. But I don't want to write in Pascal language and I need something really simple.

Comment: DEP does not prevent the execution of instructions from memory that is explicitly marked for execution via VirtualAlloc() or VirtualProtect(). There are frameworks, like the VCL and ATL, that dynamically allocate executable memory chucks for use as callback thunks, and DEP works fine for that.

Comment: There are also expression evaluators that do. But they usually mimic stack machines, and thus only need one register loaded with the stackpointer, if the code is PIC